# Google Drive API v3 find all files in folder and children

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I have google api client for java script
I created all requests.
Last request in my app it is get all files in folder and children folders.
It is request get all files in parent folder.

```
   let files = await obj.staticProperty.gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'q': `'${object['folder']['id']}' in parents`,
                'pageSize': 10
            })
```

How can i get also all files in children folders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it recursively, note that I have a callback that collects files - I'm using Redux with React so it just dispatches an action that adds the bunch of files to the state each time the method gets more files:

```
function getAllFiles(bearerToken, pageToken = undefined, q = undefined,
                     callback = (files) => console.log('No callback provided',
                         files),
                     onComplete = () => console.log('No onComplete provided'),
) {
  axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
    params: {
      corpora: 'user',
      fields: 'files(id,name,size,mimeType,parents,webViewLink,trashed),nextPageToken',
      // q: 'mimeType = \'application/vnd.google-apps.folder\'',
      q: q,
      pageSize: 1000,
      pageToken: pageToken,
    },
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearerToken,
    },
  }).then((result) => {
    callback(result.data.files);
    if (result.data.nextPageToken) {
      getAllFiles(bearerToken, result.data.nextPageToken, q, callback,
          onComplete);
    } else {
      onComplete();
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error folders result', error);
  });
}
```

This is from the code for my "Drive Dashboard" at https://drivedashboard.saisols.com/

Comment: Thanks. It is great example. 
In my code i am using second function for this. And I use Promise. 
I thought that there is a similar method the same as for all files from the root directory.